# Dragging cell to bottom or top will stop and reordering `collectionView` will not reorder

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I add a longPress Gesture to `collectionView`, and use system API to implement reordering collectionview. here is my code:

```
CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:_collectionView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:point];
if (!indexPath) {
    return;
}
DragableCollectionViewCell *tempCell = (DragableCollectionViewCell *)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

switch (sender.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

        [tempCell showDeletButton];
        [tempCell.deleteButton zkj_addEventHandler:^(id sender) {
            [tempCell hideDeleteButton];
            [self.dataSource[indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
            [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
        } withControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [_collectionView beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
        [_collectionView updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition:point];
    }
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
        [_collectionView endInteractiveMovement];
    }
        break;

    default:
        [_collectionView cancelInteractiveMovement];
        break;
}
```

and I had implement dataSource and delegate of `collectionView` correctly. After that, it works, I can move drag cell and reorder `collectionView`. But when I drag cell to bottom or top, the cell will stop at bottom or top, and `collectionView` will not reorder automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In **iOS-11**,

You can use **Drag and Drop** API for **reordering** in `UICollectionView`. 
It is much more flexible and easy to implement than your custom implementation.

Refer to the below link for a nice tutorial on how to implement that:
 https://medium.com/@p.gpt10/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313

Comment: I can not open your link. Could you tell how can I find more information of ' Drag and Drop API for reordering in UICollectionView'? And I did not use a custom implementation, I just use API in iOS-9 @PGDev

Comment: The link is working fine for me. What are you getting after clicking the link?

Comment: https://medium.com/@p.gpt10/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313

Comment: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID，and target of my development target is iOS-9, so I must find how to deal this problem instead of using a new method available in ios11